# copy specific values from text file to another excel sheet using vba

Tags: vba, excel

[This is the result what i want](https://www.dropbox.com/s/frevwb1ovafpynp/Expected_Result.xlsx?dl=0)
[This is the source file link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oigqpn15ou84b3e/Source.txt?dl=0)

I am trying to extract certain data from a text

`file(C:\Users\mondals\Desktop\Source.txt)` into an Excel spreadsheet. I'm using MS Office 2010 . I saved my files as TEXT formatted files and now I need to pull information from the text files.Here is a list of the information I need to extract from the text file:
Lines starting with

```
103 0 TestTime
203 0 TestTime
303 0 TestTime
403 0 TestTime
503 0 TestTime
603 0 TestTime
703 0 TestTime
803 0 TestTime
```

Example:

```
103 0 TestTime -1 0.0000 mSec 60.3948 mSec 4000.0000 mSec 0.0000 m 0
```

from this lines I want to copy 60.3948 and so on.

Note: Please go through the attached doc Result.xlsx

And ....

from following line i want copy the values

```
104 0 TimeStdDev
204 0 TimeStdDev
304 0 TimeStdDev
404 0 TimeStdDev
504 0 TimeStdDev
604 0 TimeStdDev
704 0 TimeStdDev
804 0 TimeStdDev
```

Example: 104 0 TimeStdDev -1 0.0000 mSec 2.6139 mSec 10000.0000 mSec 0.0000 m 0
from this line i have to copy 2.6139.

Attached sample txt           file and required output excel file

txt file=Source.txt          this thetxt  file i have

Xlsx file= Result.xlsx    This is the excel i want

Note: Please go through the links n the top

Really appreciate your help!!!!

Here"s what i have tried

```
Sub Demo()
    v = ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\subhajit\Desktop\Autmation\data.txt"
    If Dir(v) = "" Then Beep: Exit Sub
    F% = FreeFile
    Open v For Input As #F
    v = Filter(Filter(Split(Input(LOF(F), #F), vbNewLine), vbTab), "TestTime Avg")
    Close #F
    If UBound(v) < 0 Then Beep: Exit Sub
    ReDim VA#(0 To UBound(v), 0)
    For F = 0 To UBound(v):  VA(F, 0) = Val(Split(v(F), vbTab)(1)):  Next
    With Worksheets(1).Cells(1)
       .CurrentRegion.Clear
        Resize(F).Value = VA
    End With
    v = ThisWorkbook.Path & "C:\Users\subhajit\Desktop\Autmation\data.txt"
    If Dir(v) = "" Then Beep: Exit Sub
    F% = FreeFile
    Open v For Input As #F
    v = Filter(Filter(Split(Input(LOF(F), #F), vbNewLine), vbTab), "TestTime StdDev")
    Close #F
    If UBound(v) < 0 Then Beep: Exit Sub
    ReDim VA#(0 To UBound(v), 0)
    For F = 0 To UBound(v):  VA(F, 0) = Val(Split(v(F), vbTab)(1)):  Next
    With Worksheets(1).Cells(2)
       'CurrentRegion.Clear = False
       .Resize(F).Value = VA
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: All this time you spent editing your question, you could be researching for an answer you know.

Comment: I have tried ,But not getting the exact result ,,so i posted here

Comment: And final editing done  now plz help with this

Comment: Oh ok. Well, no one is going to download a file from some stranger on the internet so you're going to have to format your data properly before anyone can help you :/

Comment: Can i have your mail id,So that i can send you the files,if pssible

Comment: You miss my point XD No one is going to risk opening a random file from the internet :/